# How to send notification based on host and not service in Nagios?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, nagios

Who that gets notifications are defined in the service and host definitions, but what I would like is that it is only defined on a pr host level.

So whoever that is in the `contact_groups` for the host also get all service notifications.

For this particular host definition `example` would I like the groups `admins` and `sandradebug` to receive all host and service notifications.

Is that possible?

**Typical host definition**

```
define host {
  use                     linux-host
  host_name               example
  alias                   example
  address                 10.10.10.10
  hostgroups              default-linux-services
  contact_groups          +sandradebug
}
```

**Service check that all Linux hosts get**

```
define service {
  use                     generic-service
  name                    check_disks
  service_description     Check Disk
  check_command           check_nrpe!check_disk
  contact_groups          linux-admins
  hostgroup_name          default-linux-services
}
```

**Don't know what this does, or why it is required**

```
define hostgroup {
  hostgroup_name  default-linux-services
  alias           All Linux hosts shall have these service checks
  members         
}
```

**Service template**

```
define service{
  name                            generic-service
  active_checks_enabled           1
  passive_checks_enabled          1
  parallelize_check               1
  obsess_over_service             1
  check_freshness                 0
  notifications_enabled           1
  event_handler_enabled           1
  flap_detection_enabled          1
  failure_prediction_enabled      1
  process_perf_data               1
  retain_status_information       1
  retain_nonstatus_information    1
  is_volatile                     0
  check_period                    24x7
  max_check_attempts              3
  normal_check_interval           10
  retry_check_interval            2
  contact_groups                  admins
  notification_options            w,u,c,r
  notification_interval           60
  notification_period             24x7
  register                        0
}
```

Comment: maybe related?  http://serverfault.com/questions/433887/configure-nagios-to-alert-depending-on-host-group-that-service-alert-originates. please reread and edit you question.  The first sentance is very hard to follow.

Comment: @Zoredache Sorry my laziness got the best of me and didn't even search for a duplicate.

Comment: -1. I don't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

I'd guess adding a `contact` and then adding `contacts +sandradebug` on your host definition should do it. [Here's the object definitions](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/objectdefinitions.html#contact)

You can also set a `contactgroup` linux-admins and a `contact` sandradebug

Then create a contactgroup for linux-admins and sandradebug
For instance

```
define contactgroup{
contactgroup_name   everyone
alias   alias
members sandradebug
contactgroup_members    linux-admins
    }
```

An easier solution might be to just add comma separated contact groups or contacts.

EDIT 2:

Example for a couple of hosts

define host {
  use                     linux-host
  host_name               example
  alias                   example
  address                 10.10.10.10
  hostgroups              default-linux-services
  contacts                +sandradebug
}

Or you could add it on the service

```
define service {
  use                     generic-service
  name                    check_disks
  service_description     Check Disk
  check_command           check_nrpe!check_disk
  contact_groups          linux-admins
  hostgroup_name          default-linux-services
  contacts                +sandradebug
}
```

If you have many hosts that you want to do this create a contactgroup and include it
into the host and service groups respectively

Comment: This will apply it to all hosts and services and the question is a little more fine grained. Please read the OP again.

Comment: Made a slight edit you should add `contacts +sandradebug` on your host definition. That won't apply to all hosts and services. As for the second option again it won't apply it everywhere.